# Ubuntu MATE - Window Border changes to default after reboot

Tags: themes, gtk, ubuntu-mate, metacity

I have recently installed a few themes on Ubuntu MATE 22.04, specifically [Midnight](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1273208). I am using [*Midnight-Blue*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh5Vs.png) for the interface and [*Midnight-BlueNight*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl7zf.png) for the window borders. Recently, I found that rebooting the machine or signing out and in again will [reset the window borders to *Yaru/Yaru-light*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTI6.png). Is there anyway of setting it to my desired window border all the time? I'm willing to add any other needed details.

[Here are some `neofetch` details if they are needed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ht0d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this myself, window borders resetting to Yaru.  Bit of a puzzle because I hadn't encounter this before when using metacity themes.  For me the solution was as follows.

Apparently, Ubuntu MATE 22.04 ignores metacity themes, after logout or reboot, if there isn't a version-1 file present.  Put a blank file named metacity-theme-1.xml next to the metacity-theme-2.xml file, in the relevant metacity-1 directory.

Comment: Where is the metacity folder? In the themes folder?

Comment: Yes. Either /home/yourusername/.themes/yourtheme/metacity-1/ or /usr/share/themes/yourtheme/metacity-1/, depending on how you added your theme(s).

Comment: Thanks, this worked, no longer defaults to Yaru ^^